# Manage custom processor exception with Rabbitmq bus

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-xd

I have made a custom processor module which could throw exception.

But when exception occurs, I can't see the stacktrace in logs file or stdout.

This is my sample code:

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = "input", outputChannel = "output")
public String transform(final String payload) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(payload)) {
        throw new MessageConversionException("payload is empty");
    }

    logger.warn("log|warn: {}", payload);

    logger.debug("log|debug: {}", payload);

    return payload.toUpperCase();
}
```

Have you any idea what is wrong ?

Thanks in advance,

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because empty string is not sent to the next stream.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of XD are you using? I just tested with 1.3.1 release and see the exception ok in the container log...

```
2016-03-22T08:55:27-0400 1.3.1.RELEASE WARN xdbus.foo.0-1 retry.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer - Retries exhausted for message (Body:'2016-03-22
...
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: foo
...
```

I suggest you enable DEBUG logging. Mine came out under WARN, however.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use the 1.3.0 release. I will try with the latest.

Comment: I have tried with the latest release (1.3.1) but it doesn't work. I have also changed log level (WARN to DEBUG), but I don't see the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

This is my sample code:

CustomProcessor.class

```
package com.mypackage.xdmodule;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessageEndpoint;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Transformer;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

@MessageEndpoint
public class CustomProcessor {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomProcessor.class);

    @Transformer(inputChannel = "input", outputChannel = "output")
    public String transform(final String payload) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(payload)) {
            logger.error("payload is empty");
            throw new MessageConversionException("payload is empty");
        }

        logger.warn("log|warn: {}", payload);

        logger.debug("log|debug: {}", payload);

        return payload.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

ModuleConfiguration.class

```
package com.mypackage.xdmodule;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class ModuleConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private CustomProcessor processor;

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel input() {
    return new DirectChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel output() {
    return new DirectChannel();
  }

}
```

My stream

```
stream create --definition "http | transform --expression=payload.toUpperCase() | custom-processor | transform --expression=1/0 | log" --name custom-stream --deploy
```

I have also added this line in xd-container-logback.groovy file:

```
logger("com.mypackage.xdmodule", DEBUG, ["STDOUT", "FILE", "AMQP"], true)
```